# How to count duplicate elements in a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a sorted array:

```
[
  'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
  'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
  'FATAL <error title="There is insufficient system memory to run this query.">'
]
```

I would like to get something like this but it does not have to be a hash:

```
[
  {:error => 'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">', :count => 2},
  {:error => 'FATAL <error title="There is insufficient system memory to run this query.">', :count => 1}
]
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The following code *prints* what you asked for. I'll let you decide on how to actually use to generate the hash you are looking for:

```
# sample array
a=["aa","bb","cc","bb","bb","cc"]

# make the hash default to 0 so that += will work correctly
b = Hash.new(0)

# iterate over the array, counting duplicate entries
a.each do |v|
  b[v] += 1
end

b.each do |k, v|
  puts "#{k} appears #{v} times"
end
```

**Note:** I just noticed you said the array is already sorted. The above code does not require sorting. Using that property may produce faster code.

Comment: I do not actually need to print it, just a hash did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I know I'm late, but, wow. Hash defaults. That's a really cool trick. Thanks!

Comment: And if you wanted to find the max occurrence (and do it in a single line): a.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, val| hash[val] += 1; hash}.entries.max_by {|entry| entry.last}   ....gotta love it!

Comment: You should learn [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) to avoid procedure coding style.

Answer (score 69):

You can do  this very succinctly (one line) by using [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003160):

```
a = ['FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
      'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
      'FATAL <error title="There is insufficient ...">']

b = a.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,i| h[i] += 1; h }

b.to_a.each {|error,count| puts "#{count}: #{error}" }
```

Will produce:

```
1: FATAL <error title="There is insufficient ...">
2: FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">
```

Comment: With Ruby 1.9+ you can use [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of `inject`: `a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[o] += 1 }`.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks, I prefer the naming of `each_with_object` since it better matches other similar method names on ruby enumerables.

Comment: Note that `each_with_object` simplifies the code a little because it doesn't require the accumulator to be the return value of the block.

Answer (score 39):

Using [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally)

```
["a", "b", "c", "b"].tally 

#=> { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 1 }
```

Note: Only for Ruby versions >= 2.7

Comment: amazing ruby stuff

Comment: Wow, and it's not even a Rails thing. Brilliant. You just saved me like 12 lines.

Answer (score 31):

If you have array like this:

```
words = ["aa","bb","cc","bb","bb","cc"]
```

where you need to count duplicate elements, a one line solution is:

```
result = words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,counts| counts[word] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 28):

A different approach to the answers above, using [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4].group_by(&:itself).map { |k,v| [k, v.count] }.to_h
# {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>1}
```

Breaking that into its different method calls:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
a = a.group_by(&:itself) # {1=>[1], 2=>[2, 2], 3=>[3, 3, 3], 4=>[4]}
a = a.map { |k,v| [k, v.count] } # [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 1]]
a = a.to_h # {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3, 4=>1}
```

[`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) was added in Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I like `(&:itself)`, that's just the right amount of clever!

Comment: A one-line as elegant as they come. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 21):

How about the following:

```
things = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
things.uniq.map{|t| [t,things.count(t)]}.to_h
```

It sort of feels cleaner and more descriptive of what we're actually trying to do.

I suspect it would also perform better with large collections than the ones that iterate over each value.

Benchmark Performance test:

```
a = (1...1000000).map { rand(100)}
                       user     system      total        real
inject                 7.670000   0.010000   7.680000 (  7.985289)
array count            0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.036650)
each_with_object       0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.214731)
group_by               0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.218581)
```

So it is quite a bit faster.

Comment: Doesn't `things.uniq` and `things.count(t)` iterate over the array?

Comment: Entirely possible it does, under the hood, so perhaps I've described that wrong. Either way, the performance gain appears to be real, I think...

Answer (score 12):

From Ruby >= 2.2 you can use [`itself`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself): `array.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)`

With some more detail:

```
array = [
  'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
  'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
  'FATAL <error title="There is insufficient system memory to run this query.">'
];

array.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
 => { "FATAL <error title=\"Request timed out.\">"=>2,
      "FATAL <error title=\"There is insufficient system memory to run this query.\">"=>1 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Personally I would do it this way:

```
# myprogram.rb
a = ['FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
'FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">',
'FATAL <error title="There is insufficient system memory to run this query.">']
puts a
```

Then run the program and pipe it to uniq -c:

```
ruby myprogram.rb | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
 2 FATAL <error title="Request timed out.">
 1 FATAL <error title="There is insufficient system memory to run this query.">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
a.uniq.inject([]){|r, i| r << { :error => i, :count => a.select{ |b| b == i }.size } }
=> [{:count=>3, :error=>1}, {:count=>2, :error=>2}, {:count=>1, :error=>3}]
```

Comment: Oh, don't do that. You're reiterating through the whole array for each value!

Comment: there are good solutions up there. just want to mention the existance of array#count:
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3];
a.uniq.inject([]){|r, i| r << { :error => i, :count => a.count(i) } }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this often I suggest to do this:

```
# lib/core_extensions/array/duplicates_counter
module CoreExtensions
  module Array
    module DuplicatesCounter
      def count_duplicates
        self.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, counter| counter[element] += 1 }.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.to_h
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Load it with

```
Array.include CoreExtensions::Array::DuplicatesCounter
```

And then use from anywhere with just:

```
the_ar = %w(a a a a a a a  chao chao chao hola hola mundo hola chao cachacho hola)
the_ar.duplicates_counter
{
           "a" => 7,
        "chao" => 4,
        "hola" => 4,
       "mundo" => 1,
    "cachacho" => 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since #tally is for 2.7 and up, and I'm not there yet, it's easy to use the #count method on the array. Use #uniq on the array to get one copy of each member of the array, and then find #count for that member in the array:

```
counts=Hash.new
arr.uniq.each {|name| counts[name]=arr.count(name) }
```

Example:

```
arr = [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
arr.uniq => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
counts=Hash.new; arr.uniq.each {|name| counts[name]=arr.count(name) }
```

gives us

```
counts => {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>5, 4=>2, 5=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation:

```
(errors_hash = {}).default = 0
array_of_errors.each { |error| errors_hash[error] += 1 }
```

Comment: That first line could be written more clearly using `errors_hash = Hash.new(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample array:

```
a=["aa","bb","cc","bb","bb","cc"]
```

1. Select all the unique keys.
2. For each key, we'll accumulate them into a hash to get something like this: `{'bb' => ['bb', 'bb']}`

```
    res = a.uniq.inject({}) {|accu, uni| accu.merge({ uni => a.select{|i| i == uni } })}
    {"aa"=>["aa"], "bb"=>["bb", "bb", "bb"], "cc"=>["cc", "cc"]}
```

Now you are able to do things like:

```
res['aa'].size
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def find_most_occurred_item(arr)
    return 'Array has unique elements already' if arr.uniq == arr
    m = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
    m.each do |k, v|
        a = arr.max_by { |v| m[v] }
        if v > a
            puts "#{k} appears #{v} times"
        elsif v == a
            puts "#{k} appears #{v} times"
        end 
    end
end

puts find_most_occurred_item([1, 2, 3,4,4,4,3,3])
```