# How to group numbers into different buckets in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a file with numbers on each line:

```
0101
1010
1311
0101
1311
431
1010
431
420
```

I want have a hash with the number of occurrences of each number, in this case:

```
{0101 => 2, 1010 => 2, 1311 => 2, 431 => 2, 420 => 1}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think I found the same question with different wording :) [count duplicate elements in ruby array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569694/count-duplicate-elements-in-ruby-array)

Comment: FYI: If it happens to be Rails, you can use Enumerable#group_by. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: Enumerable#group_by is not just for Rails: It's in Ruby 1.9, and has been backported to 1.8.7

Comment: `0101` isn't a number, it's a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple one-liner, given an array `items`:

```
items.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, item| hash[item] += 1; hash}
```

How it works:

`Hash.new(0)` creates a new Hash where accessing undefined keys returns 0.

`inject(foo)` iterates through an array with the given block. For the first iteration, it passes `foo`, and on further iterations, it passes the return value of the last iteration.

Another way to write it would be:

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
items.each {|item| hash[item] += 1}
```

Comment: I tend to do it the second way @Chuck showed because then I don't have to explain it, though I prefer using `inject()`.

Comment: The each_with_object should now be the preferred, cleaner, solution - very easy to forget ; hash.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially the same as Chuck's, but when you are creating an array or hash, 'each_with_object' will make it slightly simpler than 'inject', as you do not have to write the final array or hash in the block.

```
items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|item, hash| hash[item] += 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ID = -> x { x } # Why is the identity function not in the core lib?

f = <<-HERE
  0101
  1010
  1311
  0101
  1311
  431
  1010
  431
  420
HERE

Hash[f.lines.map(&:to_i).group_by(&ID).map {|n, ns| [n, ns.size] }]
# { 101 => 2, 1010 => 2, 1311 => 2, 431 => 2, 420 => 1 }
```

You simply group the numbers by themselves using `Enumerable#group_by`, which gives you something like

```
{ 101 => [101, 101], 420 => [420] }
```

And then you `Enumerable#map` the value arrays to their lengths, i.e. `[101, 101]` becomes `2`. Then just convert it back to a `Hash` using `Hash::[]`.

However, if you are willing to use a third-party library, it becomes even more trivial, because if you use a `MultiSet` data structure, the answer falls out naturally. (A `MultiSet` is like a `Set`, except that an item can be added multiple times and the `MultiSet` will keep count of how often an item was added – which is exactly what you want.)

```
require 'multiset' # Google for it, it's so old that it isn't available as a Gem

Multiset[*f.lines.map(&:to_i)]
# => #<Multiset:#2 101, #2 1010, #2 1311, #2 431, #1 420>
```

Yes, that's it.

That's the beautiful thing about using the right data-structure: your algorithms become massively simpler. Or, in this particular case, the algorithm just *vanishes*.

I've written more about using `MultiSet`s for solving this exact problem at

- [find the repetition of duplicate numbers.](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4231534/#4232851) (the first example in that post is the same as the second one here, the second example in that post is essentially the same as @Chuck's here and the third one is the same as the first in this post.)
- [Counting occurrences of unique letters in a string](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3735605/#3737892) (the Ruby example is the same as here, the Scala and ECMAScript examples are the same as @Chuck's and the C# example is the same as my `group_by` example here.)
- [Bag/Multiset in scala and a touch of multimap](http://Article.GMaNe.Org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/33698/) (Again the same three examples as my two and @Chuck's in Scala.)

Comment: "Why is the identity function not in the core lib?" - because neither of us has suggested it should be in the core lib?

Comment: Maybe we could ask `tap` to accept the absence of a block. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308470/ruby-method-that-returns-itself/6309488#6309488