# How to find the unique elements, and the occurrrence count of each one, in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array with some elements. How can I get the number of occurrences of each element in the array?

For example, given:

```
a = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'fish']
```

The result should be:

```
a2 #=> {'cat' => 1, 'dog' => 1, 'fish' => 2}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to group numbers into different buckets in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300163/how-to-group-numbers-into-different-buckets-in-ruby)

Answer (score 44):

You can use `Enumerable#group_by` to do this:

```
res = Hash[a.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
#=> {"cat"=>1, "dog"=>1, "fish"=>2}
```

Comment: IMHO, too much complexity caused by sub-array copying.

Comment: @dadooda, complexity is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Note that since Ruby 2.7 the tally method does exactly this https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally. So this isn't the best answer anymore.

Answer (score 27):

```
a2 = a.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |a, b| a[b] += 1; a }
#=> {"cat"=>1, "fish"=>2, "dog"=>1}
```

Comment: `Hash.new(0)` with a default preset value is nicely used!

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 2.7 has [tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) method for this.

**tally → a_hash**

Tallies the collection, i.e., counts the occurrences of each element. Returns a hash with the elements of the collection as keys and the corresponding counts as values.

```
['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'fish'].tally  

=> {"cat"=>1, "dog"=>1, "fish"=>2}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
a2 = {}
a.uniq.each{|e| a2[e]= a.count(e)}
```

Comment: `count` has to traverse the entire array. Doing this for every value is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 8):

In 1.9.2 you can do it like this, from my experience quite a lot of people find `each_with_object` more readable than `reduce/inject` (the ones who know about it at least):

```
a = ['cat','dog','fish','fish']
#=> ["cat", "dog", "fish", "fish"]

a2 = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |animal, hash| hash[animal] += 1 }
#=> {"cat"=>1, "dog"=>1, "fish"=>2}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `count` method of [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000282) to get the count.

```
a.count('cat')
```

Comment: This would be a good solution if he really only needs one count at any given time. However, it is inefficient to do a large list this way.

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {}

a.each do |e|
  m[e] = 0 if m[e].nil?
  m[e] = m[e] + 1
end

puts m
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a.inject({}){|h, e| h[e] = h[e].to_i+1; h }
#=> {"cat"=>1, "fish"=>2, "dog"=>1}
```

or n2 solution

```
a.uniq.inject({}){|h, e| h[e] = a.count(e); h }
#=> {"cat"=>1, "fish"=>2, "dog"=>1}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = ['cat','dog','fish','fish']
a2 = Hash[a.uniq.map {|i| [i, a.count(i)]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```rb
['cat','dog','fish','fish'].group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count)
=> {
     "cat" => 1,
     "dog" => 1,
    "fish" => 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['cat','dog','fish','fish']
a2 = Hash.new(0)
a.each do |e|
    a2[e] += 1
end
a2
```

Answer (score 0):

ruby fu!

```
count = Hash[Hash[rows.group_by{|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k, v.count]}].sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse]
```