# Ruby method that returns itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection

I am doing some reflection, and ran into an unexpected road block.

**Is there an object method in ruby (or rails) that returns itself**

```
ruby-1.9.2> o = Object.new
 => #<Object:0x00000104750710> 
ruby-1.9.2> o.class
 => Object 
ruby-1.9.2> o.send :self
NoMethodError: undefined method `self' for #<Object:0x00000104750710>
```

What I want

```
ruby-1.9.2> o.send :self
 => #<Object:0x00000104750710>
```

Is this built in?  Or do I need to extend Object (It always gets me nervous opening up Object):

```
class Object

  def itself
    self
  end

end
```

And then so:

```
ruby-1.9.2> o.send :itself
 => #<Object:0x00000104750710>
```

---

Ok, some background on what I am trying to achieve.  I have a generic table helper in my rails app, and you call if like so:

```
  render_list @person, [{field: :name, link_to: :itself},
                        {field: {address: :name}, link_to: :address}]
```

I was struggling on the right way to call `:itself` -- but i'm thinking that my patch is the way to go.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. `self` is not exactly a method in this case, as far as I know, but a reference to the current context. Are you expecting `o.self` to be different from `o` somehow?

Comment: Maybe people could provide a more useful answer if you gave an example of what your end goal is?

Comment: You know, you'd probably be better off interpreting a parameter differently than patching Object. For instance: `link_to: true` is interpreted as "link to yourself", or you could add an exception in your method calling routine for `:self` to mean the same thing.

Comment: In the end, if you decide to patch the method `itself` to any class, try to narrow down it to ActiveRecord or whatever object are you receiving there.

Comment: Why not just `link_t: @person` (or whatever object you need)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes!  If you have Ruby 2.2.0 or later, you can use the `Kernel#itself` method.

You can see the extensive discussion of this feature here:  https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373.  The patch was submitted by Rafael França in message #53.

You can see it in the official Ruby source by looking in [object.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c).

Comment: Also, if you're using Rails (or just Active Support), you should have this even on older Ruby versions.

Answer (score 7):

There is a discussion about adding such method: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ruby version >= 1.9 you can use `tap` method with empty block:

```
Object.tap{}     => Object
Object.new.tap{} => #<Object:0x5f41334>
```

Comment: neat -- i never knew about this method

Comment: Unfortunately the required block means you can't just pass around a reference to :tap blindly, you have to be sure to always call it with the block.

Answer (score 4):

`self` *is* the object itself, no need to extra fetch it. After your patch, try the following:

```
>> a=[2,3,4] #=> [2, 3, 4]
>> a == a.itself #=> true
>> a.object_id #=> 71056290
>> a.itself.object_id #=> 71056290
```

...it is exactly the same

Comment: You can just use "o" whenever you'd use "o.itself". In other words, there's no need to patch ruby.

Comment: In fact it makes sense -- `[1,2,3].index_by(&:itself)`, but I am now more inclined towards defining `lambda{|*x| x}` globally

Comment: This is a much better solution IMHO

Comment: this is the only solution that can be in a functional way like `[nil, 1, 2, 3].find(&:itself)
=> 1
`

Answer (score 3):

`self` is a keyword referring to the default receiver.  It is not a method.  See [this page](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2008/04/17/the-rules-of-ruby-self) for an example.

Your `itself` method works fine.  You can also say:

```
o.instance_eval('self')
```

For a class, use `class_eval` instead:

```
Object.class_eval('self')
```

Comment: `o.instance_eval('self')` is a pretty crazy way of saying `o`.

Comment: @tadman -- sometimes necessary, ie. in my case I am doing some reflection where i need this functionality

Answer (score 0):

There is a #yourself method in Smalltalk. It has sense because of the syntax of the language where you can send several messages to the same object and want to get the object itself at the end of the phrase.

```
aList add: (anObjet doThis; andThat; yourself).
```

Also in Smalltalk the default return value for a method is self, but in Ruby it's the last instruction's return value (or nil if there is nothing in the method).
Anyway maybe we should all start using explicit returns :)

If for some weird logic reason you have to call a method on some object but what you want is really the object itself, then I don't see why you couldn't extend the Object class to do just that.

There's really no reason why it would break your program unless the method exists somewhere else (did or will exist) and did (or will) do something else. Maybe a slight loss in performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try .presence

```
>> a=[2,3,4]
 => [2, 3, 4] 
>> a == a.presence
 => true
```

Comment: FYI, this looks like a rails method, not just plain ruby.