# Ruby sums of objects in array equal to zero

Tags: ruby, arrays

Write a method that finds if an array of numbers has a pair that sums to zero. Be careful of the case of zero; there needs to be two zeroes in the array to make a pair that sums to zero.

Below is the code that I wrote, but I know that it is wrong. I know that at some point it will be adding itself so if there is only one 0 in my array, then it will still return true. I am new to programming and Ruby so any advice will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    def has_zero?(array)
        left, right = [-1,1]
        lefter=[]
        righter=[]
        righter=array.each {|x| x+= array[right]}
        lefter=array.each {|x| x+= array[left]}
        if lefter.include?(0) || righter.include?(0)
            return true
        else return false
        end
        left,right = [left-1,right+1]
    end
```

Comment: Your sample input data is missing. Show that, and what you mean by "has a pair". Any two numbers or two consecutive numbers?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed as "too localized". It is the 2-sum problem, a variant of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has some built-in methods that make this pretty easy:

```
def has_zero_sum_pair?(a)
  a.permutation(2).any?{|pair| pair.inject(:+) == 0}
end
```

`a.permutation(2)` gives you every pair in `a`.  `any?` returns `true` if the block ever returns `true`.  `inject(:+)` is an easy way to get the sum of an array.

```
has_zero_sum_pair?([1, 2, 3])
# => false 
has_zero_sum_pair?([1, 2, 3, -2])
# => true 
has_zero_sum_pair?([1, 2, 3, 0])
# => false 
has_zero_sum_pair?([0, 1, 2, 3, 0])
# => true
```

**Update:** If I didn't know about [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) and had to accomplish this in the first way that came to mind, or if I was concerned about performance, I'd probably do something like this:

```
def has_zero_sum_pair2?(a)
  (0..a.length-2).each do |i|
    (i+1..a.length-1).each do |j|
      return true if a[i] + a[j] == 0
    end
  end
  false
end
```

I find that uglier and more error-prone, and it took longer to write.  But it's about four times faster with small arrays and 10 times faster for larger arrays.  It's typical in programming to have an easy way that works well enough in most cases but isn't ideal in performance.  Sometimes better performance can be attained without costing clarity by choosing a better algorithm or data structure.  Often a trade-off has to be made.

**Update 2:** If I really cared about performance, I'd use @FMc's technique.  That's a great example of using a better data structure and algorithm for huge performance gains.

Comment: I'd suggest showing the version without `inject` alongside the one using it, to make it clearer to a beginner just what it's doing :)

Comment: As a warning: `permutation` can get really slow when the array gets big.

Comment: Yea is there a more "beginner" way of doing this without using "permutation"? i just started learning programming last week and I barely even know the inject method. thanks

Comment: @user2391263 There are harder ways to do it.  As a beginner, if anything, it makes *more* sense to lean on built-in methods.  It's okay, and encouraged, to consult the documentation and learn what Ruby provides for you.

Comment: Thanks, but what do u mean "consult the documentation"? What is the best way to do that? sorry i am a complete beginner to programming.

Comment: @user2391263 ruby-doc.org is the canonical place, but you can always just Google for `ruby array` and get there.

Answer (score 1):

This works except for zero.

```
[1, 2, 3, -2]
.uniq.group_by(&:abs).any?{|_, tuple| tuple.length == 2}
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem calls for a `Hash`.

```
vals = [0, 4, 3, 0, -3, 2, -2, 1, 3, -4, -4]

# Our hash:
# groups[X] = Array of vals equal to X
groups = vals.group_by { |v| v }

# Just check whether the hash contains a pair
# of keys X and -X, or whether the original array
# had more than one zero in it.
p groups.any? { |k, vs| k == 0 ? vs.size > 1 : groups.has_key?(-k) }
```

You can generalize to any `target` sum by changing the test slightly:

```
k == target / 2 ? vs.size > 1 : groups.has_key?(target - k)
```

Comment: This is clever, and very, very fast.

Comment: BTW: your `group_by` screams for an identity function in the stdlib. I usually have one in my toolbelt: `ID = ->x {x}`. Then, your `group_by` becomes `vals.group_by(&ID)`. If you are used to, say, Haskell, where there is an `id` in the `Prelude`, this is much more readable.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yeah, I thought exactly the same thing! I thought for sure I was overlooking something. Did find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308470.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [1,2,3,-2,0,0]

array.any?{|a| array.rindex(-a) > array.index(a)}
```

Check to see if the negative of any item is further to the right in the array.  (rindex finds the index of the last occurance in the array.)