# Iteration in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count duplicate elements in ruby array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569694/count-duplicate-elements-in-ruby-array)

I just started learning ruby and I wish to achieve something like this.
Let say I have an array

```
["student", "student", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher"]
```

What I'm trying to do is to count the number of student and teacher and store it into a hash, so that i can get

```
{:student= > 2, :teacher=> 3}
```

Could someone give me some kind of direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569694/count-duplicate-elements-in-ruby-array) answer, which gives this example:

```
# sample array
a=["aa","bb","cc","bb","bb","cc"]

# make the hash default to 0 so that += will work correctly
b = Hash.new(0)

# iterate over the array, counting duplicate entries
a.each do |v|
  b[v] += 1
end

b.each do |k, v|
  puts "#{k} appears #{v} times"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ["student", "student", "teacher"]

# Initializing the hash with value 0 so that we can use += 1
count = Hash.new(0)  

list.each {|el| count[el] += 1}

#Number of student  
count['student']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xs.inject({}) { |acc, x| acc.update(x => (acc[x] || 0) + 1) }
#=> {"student"=>2, "teacher"=>3}
```

Or:

```
xs.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x, acc| acc[x] += 1 }
#=> {"student"=>2, "teacher"=>3}
```

Comment: Will `fetch` make it faster than `update`?

Comment: @sawa. But isn't `fetch` a get operation? But now that you mention it, the value can also be written `(acc.fetch(x, 0) + 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem is a great example of how choosing the right algorithm, but even more importantly the right *data structure* can massively simplify the solution. In fact, in this particular case, choosing the right data structure will make the algorithm so trivial that it basically completely vanishes: the data structure already *is* the answer.

The data structure I am talking about is a `Multiset`: a `Multiset` is like a `Set`, except it doesn't store only unique items, instead it stores a count of how often each item is in the `Multiset`. Basically, a `Set` tells you whether a particular item is in the `Set` *at all*, a `Multiset` in addition also tells you *how often* that particular item is in the `Multiset`.

Unfortunately, there is no `Multiset` implementation in the Ruby core library or standard library, but there are a couple of implementations floating around the web.

You literally just have to construct a `Multiset` from your `Array`. Here's an example:

```
require 'multiset'

ary = ["student", "student", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher"]

print Multiset[*ary]
```

Yes, that's all there is to it. This prints:

```
#2 "student"
#3 "teacher"
```

And that's it. Example, using https://GitHub.Com/Josh/Multimap/:

```
require 'multiset'

histogram = Multiset.new(*ary)
# => #<Multiset: {"student", "student", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher"}>

histogram.multiplicity('teacher')
# => 3
```

Example, using http://maraigue.hhiro.net/multiset/index-en.php:

```
require 'multiset'

histogram = Multiset[*ary]
# => #<Multiset:#2 'student', #3 'teacher'>
```

Another possibility is to use a `Hash`, which basically just means that instead of the `Multiset` taking care of the element counting for you, you have to do it yourself:

```
histogram = ary.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hsh, item| hsh.tap { hsh[item] += 1 }}
print histogram
# { "student" => 2, "teacher" => 3 }
```

But you can have that easier if instead of counting yourself, you use `Enumerable#group_by` to group the elements by themselves and then map the groupings to their sizes. Lastly, convert back to a `Hash`:

```
Identity = ->x { x }

print Hash[[ary.group_by(&Identity).map {|n, ns| [n, ns.size] }]
# { "student" => 2, "teacher" => 3 }
```

Comment: Last two of your solutions are already given in different answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4300282/38765 has another mention of Multisets, plus links to other mentions of Multisets.

Answer (score 0):

It really has been done to death here on SO, but I suggest:

```
Hash[*a.group_by{|x| x}.flat_map{|k, v| [k.to_sym,v.size]}]
#=> {:student=>2, :teacher=>3}
```

Comment: `Hash[]` accepts pairs since Ruby 1.8.7, no need to * + flatten.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["student", "student", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher"]

a.inject({}){|h, e| h[e] ||= a.count(e); h}
# => {"student"=>2, "teacher"=>3}
```

Comment: As happens with @RailsN00ob's answer, this is O(n^2)

Comment: @tokland I think it is less than O(n^2). Because of `||=`, it skips unnecessary iterations. When it skips, it is just a hash look up: `h[e]`, which should be quick. I initially had an answer which is the same as RailsN00b's, and realized what you mention, and changed to what I have now. My answer is more effective than that.

Comment: Yes, it potentially perfoms better thanks to the memoization of the counts, O(n*k) where k is the unique elements in `a`. So best case O(n), worst case still O(n^2). But in a clear a O(n) problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["student", "student", "teacher", "teacher", "teacher"] #original list

counts = {} #where the count hash will be

list.uniq.map{|x| counts[x]= list.count(x)}
```

for every unique item in the list put the count of it from the original list in the counts hash.

one line. clean and simple.

Comment: map O(n) with count O(n) -> O(n^2). Terrible performance.

Comment: see the question. he just started to learn ruby. performance is not an issue.