# Rails Unlimited Self Joins As Alias

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm writing a program where items have multiple characteristics and multiple values, and values belong to items and characteristics. I need to be able to join values and characteristics to the items table multiple times each (an unlimited number of times).

Is there a way to get join tables that look like this with ruby syntax?

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
INNER JOIN characteristics ON characteristics.item_id = items.id AS characteristics1
INNER JOIN values ON value_items.item_id = item.id AS value1
INNER JOIN characteristics ON characteristics.item_id = items.id AS characteristics2
INNER JOIN values ON value_items.item_id = item.id AS value2
WHERE characteristics1.id = 1 AND
WHERE values1.value = "foo" AND
WHERE characteristics2.id = 2 AND
WHERE values2.value = "bar"
```

That's at a minimum, I actually need to be able to chain an unlimited number of self joins.

EDIT: Working toward a solution - not there yet.

```
Item.joins(:values).where("values.value=?", "foo").where("values.characteristic_id = 2")
```

This works to find me items based on one of the characteristics. However, when I try to find items that satisfy criteria on multiple characteristics I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record`

I get that error when I try either of these two solutions:

```
Item.joins(:values).where("values.value=?", ["foo", "bar"]).where("values.characteristic_id=?", [1, 2])

Item.includes(:values).where("values.value=?", ["foo", "bar"]).where("values.characteristic_id=?", [1, 2]).references(:values)
```

Comment: It would be great if you share the relationships between the models and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is allowing users to create their own tables. Users decide what characteristics they want, assign values to those characteristics, and then are able to sort and filter their own user generated tables that way. This way, users can assign an unlimited number of characteristics to their table.

Comment: Won't let me edit for some reason or I'd just put the relations on the OP. Item has_many :values. Value belongs_to :item. Value belongs_to :characteristic. Characteristic has_many :values. Characteristic belongs_to :collection. Collection has_many :items. Collection has_many :characteristics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good Solution**

I basically just forgot how aliases work. This is what I want:

```
Item.joins("INNER JOIN values v1 on v1.item_id = items.id")
.joins("INNER JOIN values v2 on v2.item_id = items.id")
.where(v1: {characteristic_id: 1, value: "foo"})
.where(v2: {characteristic_id: 2, value: "bar})
```

**Terrible Solution**

I've found a temporary solution using ruby outside of ActiveRecord.

```
search1 = Item.joins(:values).where(values: {characteristic_id: 1, value: "foo"})

search2 = Item.joins(:values).where(values: {characteristic_id: 2, value: "bar"})

Item.find(search1.map(&:id) & search2.map(&:id))
```

I might actually have to do this recursively, since I can't define search1 and search2 variables, since I need an unlimited number of searches. Or maybe metaprogramming.

It would definitely be better to do this in a single query though. Maybe I just have to write a method that generates the raw SQL. Still looking for a way to get aliases on joins through rails though.

Comment: Good solution , using pluck will be more faster rather than map though. You could create a scope for this in your model and you could use the same scope where ever you need to use.

Comment: I think the map solution is a bad solution anyway. What I needed was that "values v1" part of the top solution.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have relations in your models,
`Items.includes(:characteristics,:value_items).where('characteristics.id=?',[1,2]).references(:characteristics).where('values_items.value=?',['foo','bar']).references(:value_items)`

Comment: I'm getting: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record

Comment: Please show what query you are using also relationships in models i.e Item,Characterstics and ValueItem

Comment: Edited Original Question.

Comment: `Item.joins(:values).where("values.value IN (?)", ["foo", "bar"]).where("values.characteristic_id IN (?)", [1, 2])`, 
I found this syntax (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900297/rails-where-sql-query-on-array]

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't work for me. Let's say I'm sorting a collection of Magic Cards. They have characteristic color, and characteristic cost. I only want to find Blue cards that cost 2. So I want to find characteristic color, value blue && characteristic cost, value 2. IN, doesn't do this. It will find all blue cards and all 2 cost cards, not just blue 2-cost cards.

Comment: I figured out what I need, you can check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your model Active Record has the ability to utilize associations.  This will allow you to add the has_many and or belongs_to in your model files.  See example below.

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end

Rails supports six types of associations:

```
belongs_to
has_one
has_many
has_many :through
has_one :through
has_and_belongs_to_many
```

Comment: Performs a joins on args. The given symbol(s) should match the name of the association(s).

User.joins(:posts, :account) # produces the following query

# SELECT "users".*
# FROM "users"
# INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
# INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "users"."account_id"

Comment: I know how to get an inner join. It's self joining multiple times I want to know how to do within rails (I know how to do it in SQL). Going to try Vaibhav's solution tomorrow morning and make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's my answer based on the "[clarification answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38598091/305306)" that Wylliam Judd added, which states he's looking for something like this:

```
Item.joins("INNER JOIN values v1 on v1.item_id = items.id")
.joins("INNER JOIN values v2 on v2.item_id = items.id")
.where(v1: {characteristic_id: 1, value: "foo"})
.where(v2: {characteristic_id: 2, value: "bar"})
```

What no one's pointed out yet is that `INNER JOIN` can have multiple conditions for the `ON` clause (e.g. you can use `AND`).

Thus, the hand-coded SQL answer for this problem could be done like this:

```
Item.
joins("INNER JOIN values v1 ON v1.item_id = items.id AND v1.characteristic_id = 1 AND v1.value = 'foo'").
joins("INNER JOIN values v2 ON v2.item_id = items.id AND v2.characteristic_id = 2 AND v2.value = 'bar'")
```

Assuming you stick a `.all` on the end of that, you'll get all `items` records that have 2 associated records in the `values` table, one each that matches `{characteristic_id: 1, value: "foo"}` and `{characteristic_id: 2, value: "bar"}`

***But wait! There's more!***

Now that we have Rails 6, it looks like Wylliam's "wishful" code works out of the box! (I don't know if it works on previous versions, because I only have Rails 6.0.0 installed on my machine.) You *can* use the named alias (e.g. `v1`, `v2`) in the `.where` call, just like he has it:

```
Item.joins("INNER JOIN values v1 on v1.item_id = items.id")
.joins("INNER JOIN values v2 on v2.item_id = items.id")
.where(v1: {characteristic_id: 1, value: "foo"})
.where(v2: {characteristic_id: 2, value: "bar"})
```

If you slap a `.to_sql` on the end of that, you'll end up with exactly what you'd expect:

`SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN values v1 on v1.item_id = items.id INNER JOIN values v2 on v2.item_id = items.id WHERE "v1"."characteristic_id" = 1 AND "v1"."value" = 'foo' AND "v2"."characteristic_id" = 2 AND "v2"."value" = 'bar'`

Comment: Ah, no that code wasn't wishful, it worked when I wrote it.