# Given an array, returns a hash

Tags: ruby

Write a method, which given an array, returns a hash whose keys are words in the array and whose values are the number of times each word appears.

```
arr=["A", "man", "a", "plan", "a", "canal","Panama"]
# => {'a' => 3, 'man' => 1, 'canal' => 1, 'panama' => 1, 'plan' => 1}
```

How do I achieve that? Here's my code:

```
hash={}
arr.each do |i|
    hash.each do |c,v|
       hash[c]=v+1
    end
end
```

Comment: What does this have to do with regex? And what do you need help with?

Comment: You may suggest a regex approach !!

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569694/count-duplicate-elements-in-ruby-array

Comment: How to I create a hash as shown above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash = arr.inject({}) do |hash, element| 
  element.downcase!
  hash[element] ||= 0
  hash[element] += 1
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.inject­(Hash.new(­0)){|h,k| k.dow­ncase!; h[k] += 1; h}
```

Comment: could simplify to `{ |h,k| h[k.downcase] += 1; h }` for the inject?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["A", "man", "a", "plan", "a", "canal","Panama"]
r = {}
arr.each { |e| e.downcase!; r[e] = arr.count(e) if r[e].nil? }
```

Output

```
p r
#==> {"a"=>3, "man"=>1, "plan"=>1, "canal"=>1, "panama"=>1}
```