# How to parse a text file and count occurance of a string?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have text file with a list of dates

```
2014-01-18
2014-01-18
2014-01-20
2014-01-20
2014-01-20
2014-01-21
2014-01-21
2014-01-22
2014-01-22
2014-01-22
2014-01-22
2014-01-22
```

How can I count how many times each date is recorded? So have an output something similar to:

```
2014-01-18 2
2014-01-19 0
2014-01-20 3
2014-01-21 2
2014-01-22 5
```

Comment: If you just need the output: `sort textfile | uniq -c`

Comment: possible duplicate of [count duplicate elements in ruby array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569694/count-duplicate-elements-in-ruby-array)

Comment: I agree with @Stefan that using a simple shell command-line is the best way. It's fast, and easy.

Answer (score 4):

```
path = '/path/to/file'
lines = File.readlines(path).map(&:chomp)

# At this point lines should look like below, this is just for testing
lines = ["2014-01-18", "2014-01-18", "2014-01-20", 
         "2014-01-20", "2014-01-20", "2014-01-21", 
         "2014-01-21", "2014-01-22", "2014-01-22", 
         "2014-01-22", "2014-01-22", "2014-01-22"]

# All Ruby versions (since you're using Ruby 1.9.3 you should use tihs)
Hash[ lines.group_by { |v| v }.map { |k, v| [k, v.size] } ]
# Ruby >= 2.1.0
lines.group_by { |v| v }.map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_h

#=> {"2014-01-18"=>2, "2014-01-20"=>3, "2014-01-21"=>2, "2014-01-22"=>5}
```

Comment: `Hash.[]` is old fashioned.

Comment: I don't like it too, but I'm not aware of alternatives; What would you use?

Comment: Why not use `Array#to_h`?

Comment: How would I turn the text file lines into an array?

Comment: @sawa Oh! I didn't know it, it seems it was introduced in Ruby 2.1.0, thanks for the info! spuggy I'll write it, which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: @spuggy If you use a legacy version of Ruby, you should express that in the question by adding the relevant tag.

Answer (score 3):

I like using `Hash.new`

```
lines = ["2014-01-18", "2014-01-18", "2014-01-20", 
         "2014-01-20", "2014-01-20", "2014-01-21", 
         "2014-01-21", "2014-01-22", "2014-01-22", 
         "2014-01-22", "2014-01-22", "2014-01-22"]

result = Hash.new(0)
lines.each { |line| result[line] += 1 }

result
# => {"2014-01-18"=>2, "2014-01-20"=>3, "2014-01-21"=>2, "2014-01-22"=>5}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass a block, just `result = Hash.new(0)`

Comment: And, a shorter version, since I'm a one-liner guy: `lines.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |l, h| h[l] += 1 }`

Comment: @Stefan you are right, I usually use the more verbose block. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
lines = File.readlines('file.txt').map(&:chomp)

op = Hash.new(0)

lines.each do |line|
  op[line.to_sym] += 1
end

puts op.sort_by { |k, v| v }
```